# how to make custom propane fitting

Tags: gas, propane

I have a camp chef I'm installing in my teardrop and it came with a regulator but I don't need that since the 20# tank already has a regulator. I need to install a 90 degree fitting so it will point down away from the wall for maximum space.

Don't worry about it's proximity to the wall it will be on sliders so it will only be in operation while slid outside of the trailer.

Anyway it has what looks like a 3/8 NPT fitting with a extended nipple on it. Could I cut off that nipple and just connect a standard NPT fitting which would connect to the hose I have. [image: 1]

[image: regulator]

[image: fitting]

[image: nipple]

[image: inside]

Comment: Prefer not to cut, but undo/unscrew, and not try to make frankenstein fittings.  What you want is probably already available at camping/grills/propane stores.  Ask for the old guy without eyebrows, he won't make that mistake again.

Comment: So you're saying you think that bit on the end will thread off? It is smooth so the only way to grasp it would be a pipe wrench and it just seems like it's part of the main line and I didn't want to break anything. I mean the bit coming off the line where it was attached to the regulator is a 1/4 NPT but I'm trying to save as much space as possible.

Comment: The end round piece with the small hole looks like it threaded on, one or two threads showing where it goes into the bigger pipe.  Might be able to use a round rod in the small hole to unscrew, instead of a pipe wrench.

Comment: I added another pic to the original question, it looks like it's one piece. It's hard to get in there at a good angle but there aren't any threads in there

Comment: I'm thinking about taking the brass fitting out and replacing it with a 90° to 3/8 flare. But to save space instead, perhaps cut the end of and just braze on the same fitting with one side cut flush so it's as small as possible.